# Entity Framework and SQL Server user roles: how to enable EF to generate role-aware queries?

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

### Background

We have a WinForms application with Entity Framework 4.2 code-first / FluentAPI using SQL Server 2008 R2.

The security is a custom implementation of `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` with the roles for the user. These roles are checked when a Form/menu/button is displayed and it will be disabled/removed based on the user role.

Users are authenticated against the database so there is no "master" user for the connection: it's created using the username/password provided on the login screen.

So, access to data (general) is working.

### The problem

But some cases might require me to disable access to a specific table or to a column inside the table.

Some tests have shown here that `IGenericRepository.Find<MyCustomType>(_idToFind)` (which returns the complete entity) will fail because there is no access to a single column and SQL server will prevent the whole select statement.

I've found, however, that create a query like

```
IGenericRepository.All<MyCustomType>().Select(_c => _c.JustASingleField)
```

will work because the generated query will look only for a specific field for which I have access.

### Question

Is there a way for me to create queries that will be role-aware to the database?

For instance: `Find<MyCustomType>(id)` will return the object as usual but with the field that the user does not have access set to NULL or with no value?

Or I'll just have to write "generic" queries for every single item that does not require protection and rely on the security system to completely block access to a resource?

Another example would be to fill a grid but the column for which the user does not have access will be blank.

Is it possible at all using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible at all using EntityFramework?

No. EF is not aware of security configuration on SQL server and it is not able to react to any security demands expected by SQL server except providing credentials for connection string.

If you require this type of security you should use database views providing only accessible items to specific role and let EF to use model mapping only views the user role has access to - it can result in quite big set of different "models" due to many roles.

Comment: It WILL result in hundreds of models here because we have dynamically customer-created roles for each item (insert, delete, update, select for each and every table). We don't have this scenario but we simply can't say "Oh, just because we don't have that today it means we'll never have that". I thought about a custom provider but it will lead into storing each and every permission into memory AND to query that EVERY SINGLE TIME to check and create the SQL from the expression tree. Too bad this option won't go smoothly =/

Comment: If you have dynamic customer created roles you should mantain them in application and not use SQL server security. If you go with SQL server security you will have to abandon EF and work with roles in application anyway to build correct queries.

Comment: Marked as answer since Microsoft also stated that EF does not provide any support for security on the way I was trying to do. Guess I'll have to mix both. The problem is that I have an auth system that should work with roles inside my system OR with roles from the domain. I'll see what I can do, probably some sort of plugin with MEF too.

Comment: Has this changed with EF 6? Can EF 6 or 7 access the security configuration of SQL Server?